# Showing the first 6 articles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I am new to Gatsby.
So I would like to display the first 6 articles published in WordPress
Here is my Component content:

```
import React from 'react';
import {graphql, StaticQuery} from 'gatsby';

const Actualites = () => (
    <StaticQuery query={graphql`{
        allWordpressPost(filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {name: {eq: "Actualités"}}}}) {
            edges {
                node {
                    date
                    title
                        tags {
                            name
                        }
                        categories {
                            name
                        }
                        featured_media {
                            source_url
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
    } render={data =>
                 {
                     return (
                         <div className="itemList">
                            <ul>
                                {data.allWordpressPost.edges[0].node.map(
                                    prop => {
                                        return(
                                            <li className="itemNews">
                                                <span>{prop.date}</span>
                                                {data.allWordpressPost.edges[0].node.tags.map(
                                                    prop => {
                                                        return(
                                                            <span>{prop.name}</span>
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                )}
                                                {data.allWordpressPost.edges[0].node.featured_media.map(
                                                    prop => {
                                                        return(
                                                            <div className="itemImage">{prop.source_url}</div>
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                )}
                                                <div className="itemTitle">
                                                    {prop.title}
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        )
                                    }
                                )}

                            </ul>
                         </div>
                     )
                 }}
    />
);

export default Actualites;
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: data.allWordpressPost.edges[0].node.map is not a function
```

So I would like to know how to go about it.
Moreover, how to increment so that it only has the 6 most recent articles displayed?

Thank You !!!

Answer (score 0):

`data.allWordpressPost.edges[0]` is your first post since your data is stored inside is node, so you can't map it. First of all if you want your first 6 posts you need to add the `limit` GraphQL option:

```
graphql`{
        allWordpressPost(
           filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {name: {eq: "Actualités"}}}}, 
           limit: 6) {
            edges {
                node {
                    date
                    title
                        tags {
                            name
                        }
                        categories {
                            name
                        }
                        featured_media {
                            source_url
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
```

> Moreover, how to increment so that it only has the 6 most recent
> articles displayed?

You need to `sort` `DESC` by published date. Something like:

```
allWordpressPost(
    filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {name: {eq: "Actualités"}}}}, 
    limit: 6
    sort: { order: DESC, fields: [date] })
```

For further details and sorting check [Gatsby's GraphQL docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/).

Once you've queried your 6 articles you need to iterate through them to print it.

```
<ul>
  {data.allWordpressPost.edges.node.map((article) => {
    return (
      <li className="itemNews">
        <span>{article.date}</span>
        {article.tags.map((prop) => {
          return <span>{prop.name}</span>;
        })}
        {article.featured_media.map((prop) => {
          return <div className="itemImage">{article.source_url}</div>;
        })}
        <div className="itemTitle">{article.title}</div>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>;
```

I've renamed the iterable variable to `article` instead of `prop` since it's much more readable. So, in each loop, you are printing each article. Inside the main loop, you only need to iterate through `article` to get `tags` and `featured_media`.

Your final code:

```
const Actualites = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      {
        allWordpressPost(
          filter: { categories: { elemMatch: { name: { eq: "Actualités" } } } },
          limit: 6,
          sort: { fields: [date], order: DESC }
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              date
              title
              tags {
                name
              }
              categories {
                name
              }
              featured_media {
                source_url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={(data) => {
      return (
        <div className="itemList">
          <ul>
            {data.allWordpressPost.edges.node.map((article) => {
              return (
                <li className="itemNews">
                  <span>{article.date}</span>
                  {article.tags && article.tags.map((prop) => {
                    return <span>{prop.name}</span>;
                  })}
                  {article.featured_media && article.featured_media.map((prop) => {
                    return (
                      <div className="itemImage">{article.source_url}</div>
                    );
                  })}
                  <div className="itemTitle">{article.title}</div>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
          ;
        </div>
      );
    }}
  />
);

export default Actualites;
```

I've added a control to check if one post comes without `tags` (`article.tags && article.tags.map`) or `featured_media` (`article.featured_media && article.featured_media.map`). You can add an optional chaining feature of [ECMAScript 2020](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) by `article?.tags?.map` to achieve the same with less code if you have your Babel configurated to compile it.

Comment: @anohjp check that everything is properly closed. In my code it is.

Comment: everything is properly closed

Comment: This code product the follozing error: TypeError: can't access property "map", data.allWordpressPost.edges.node is undefined

Comment: Check your query in the |localhost:8000/___graphql`. Without your data structure it's impossible to know what will be the result. I've added a workaround to help you in your issue, not a simply copy paste code.

Comment: Really sorry to bother you ... Also big thank you for the help you give me ... Otherwise I had already tested since my first post. The code in the graphql generates good results.

Comment: Hmm, I've updated the answer. My guess is that one of those posts does not come with `tags` or `featured_media` to loop. I've added control. Try to debug inside the main loop.